# Angular custom Filter not working in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox

I have an issue in firefox (tested and works in chrome and IE) whereby a custom filter is not functioning. Here is the repeated template:

```
    <img src="/Images/blank.gif" ng-class="a.VolunteerStatus | classSwitch:{1:'icon  assignment_status assignment_empty',2:'icon assignment_status assignment_inactive',3:'icon assignment_status assignment_unverified',4:'icon assignment_status assignment_verified'}" ng-click="toggleVolunteerStatus(a)" title="" />
```

This basically is an image with a css class that switches based on the underlying status. Here is the filter in my module:

```
    departmentModule.filter('classSwitch', function () {
        return function (input, map) {
            return map[input] || '';
        };
    });
```

Firefox shows no bugs in the console, but **the filter in firefox ALWAYS returns the 2nd switch regardless of the underlying data**. So ALL the elements have class:icon assignment_status assignment_inactive

If it helps, here is the element rendered in Firefox:

```
    <img class="icon assignment_status assignment_inactive" src="/Images/blank.gif" ng-class="a.VolunteerStatus | classSwitch:{1:'icon assignment_status assignment_empty',2:'icon assignment_status assignment_inactive',3:'icon assignment_status assignment_unverified',4:'icon assignment_status assignment_verified'}" ng-click="toggleVolunteerStatus(a)" title="">
```

See [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/86gXqXUVVaydRAZ4Lxvj?p=preview) courtesy of Marck.

Any ideas fellow developers? Your time reading this is much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: A bit confused about this: in the description of the problem you say "ALL the elements have class: icon assignment_status assignment_empty" but in the Firefox rendered snippet the class is "icon assignment_status assignment_inactive"

Comment: Hi @Marck, yes made a typo- the question is adjusted. Thanks for the pickup.

Comment: I'm not finding that to be the case when testing this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzA6AbRnb2gVWSdrBToc?p=preview) in Firefox 29. Whenever I change the value of `a.VolunteerStatus` between 1 and 4, a different class is set. What do you see in your browser?

Comment: Hi @Marck please see this [amended plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/86gXqXUVVaydRAZ4Lxvj?p=preview). I simply added css styles to the style sheet and now if i change the values in firefox, the style isnt changed - EXCEPT for if the value is 1! However works in chrome and ie!

Comment: The CSS rules were invalid because the semicolons were outside of the brackets (take a look). I updated [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2SEXNGoKidQl4TNR3VNn?p=preview) and now it works fine again in Firefox for me ... the border colors change.

Comment: Hi @Marck, I have updated the plunkr to use CSS background images as that is what my APP uses. Please note the ammended CSS and the issue with firefox not replacing the style when you change VolunteerStatus values! Any ideas? Thank you sooo much for your time so far..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS uses a non-standard property that Firefox doesn't recognize...

For example, this:

`background-position-y: -20px;`

should be:

`background-position: 0 -20px`

I replaced those properties in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T9NCJYiAIg5N64cI6cTi?p=preview), where the icon shown does change in Firefox as you update your scope property.

Comment: Cant believe how simple that answer is....
Thanks @Marck! Reallllllly appreciated! Worked a treat. Thank you

Comment: I think I'm facing a similar issue. Is there a resource with a list of these non-standard and their supported equivalents?